# No such file or directory when trying to COPY file in docker container

Tags: bash, docker, django

This question was asked before. However I can't seem to fix this. I am trying to COPY a file to my docker container, but it keeps telling me that the directory doesn't exist, even though it does. I can copy other folders, but not this specific one.

My directory structure simplified:

```
- app
--.envs
  -- .local
    -- .django

--requirements
  -- production
  -- local
--compose
  -- morefiles
```

When I run `COPY ./requirements /requirements` then this works without a problem. But when I run `COPY ./.envs/.local/.django /` it tells me:

> Service 'django' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder264874195/.envs/.local/.django: no such file or directory

I assume is that `.envs` is being somewhere excluded but I don't know where. I checked the docker-ignore file like recommended in 
[COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder918577595/...](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34986), but also if I delete all content in the `dockerignore` I get the same error.

I tried renaming the folder without the `.` but still the same result. Not really sure what else I can try. I tried changing paths moving the command within the `Dockerfile` but nothing. I get the same behaviour with ADD.

My `docker-compose` file:

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  local_postgres_data: {}
  local_postgres_data_backups: {}

services:
  django:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/django/Dockerfile
    image: mywebsite_local_django
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.django
      - ./.envs/.local/.postgres
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: /start

  postgres:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/postgres/Dockerfile
    image: mywebsite_production_postgres
    volumes:
      - local_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - local_postgres_data_backups:/backups
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.postgres
```

And here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine


COPY ./.envs/.production/.django /
COPY ./compose/local/django/pre_deploy_hook /
RUN chmod +x /pre_deploy_hook && /pre_deploy_hook

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

ARG ADMIN_PORT=some_default_value
ENV ADMIN_PORT=${ADMIN_PORT}

ARG DJANGO_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=defaultvalueoverwritteninnextline
ENV DJANGO_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${DJANGO_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}

ARG DJANGO_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=defaultvalueoverwritteninnextline
ENV DJANGO_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${DJANGO_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}

ARG DJANGO_AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME=defaultvalueoverwritteninnextline
ENV DJANGO_AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME=${DJANGO_AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}

ARG DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=defaultvalueoverwritteninnextline
ENV DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=${DJANGO_SECRET_KEY}

RUN apk update \
  # psycopg2 dependencies
  && apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev \
  && apk add postgresql-dev \
  # Pillow dependencies
  && apk add jpeg-dev zlib-dev freetype-dev lcms2-dev openjpeg-dev tiff-dev tk-dev tcl-dev \
  # CFFI dependencies
  && apk add libffi-dev py-cffi \
  # Translations dependencies
  && apk add gettext \
  # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#dbshell
  && apk add postgresql-client \
  ## Needed for sphinx https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django/issues/1747
  && apk add make


##Needed when installing pandas as requirement
#RUN apk add --update curl gcc g++
#RUN ln -s /usr/include/locale.h /usr/include/xlocale.h

# Requirements are installed here to ensure they will be cached.
COPY ./requirements /requirements
RUN pip install -r /requirements/local.txt

COPY ./compose/production/django/entrypoint /entrypoint
RUN sed -i 's/\r//' /entrypoint
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint

COPY ./compose/local/django/start /start
RUN sed -i 's/\r//' /start
RUN chmod +x /start

WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint"]
```

Could it be that I specify the .env file in the compose file? Because by placing the file into another folder it works.... But that's not what I want...

Comment: `COPY /.envs/.local/.django /`? Should that be `COPY ./.envs/.local/.django /` or `COPY .envs/.local/.django /`?

Comment: ah yes absolutely, good catch thank you muru! But unfortunately I only mistyped it in the question. The error remains with both of your recommended options.

Comment: Please paste real code. Not an impression of it. We don't like debugging the wrong code.

Comment: apologies, will update

Comment: I would think that the dockerfile would be more relevant that the compose file.

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: Removing the .env file in my compose file actually does make it work... But this is not what I want.... I want to have env files in my container